# Travelling to Romania by train from Austria - COVID-19 quarantine risk at the border?

Tags: romania, covid-19

I will be traveling from Austria to Romania by train this weekend (exact date still to be confirmed).

**Have there been any people that recently took the train and can tell me what happens at the Romanian border (Curtici), is there any risk of being put into quarantine or home isolation?**

(General info: Romania keeps a list of red and yellow zones and all travelers from there are put either into quarantine or house isolation. Unfortunately, there is no general website that indicates which countries are classified as red/yellow/none, since there are only press releases, where this is mentioned. Since the coronavirus situation is changing rapidly, I'm not sure whether Austria is already in the yellow zone or not.)

Answer (score 1):

A [TIMATIC](http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) search reveals that visitors who have been to China, Iran, Italy or South Korea since the virus came to be will be **refused entry** to Romania.

Citizens and residents of Romania who have been to the aforementioned countries in the past 14 days will be put into quarantine or self-isolation and must fill in a declaration form.

Comment: I have been to none of the countries you quote and I am a resident of Romania. But it's still unclear to me whether quarantine or self-isolation will be apply to me; because as of now, only people coming from *some* countries will be put into quarantine or self-isolation, not all of them. Can you please be more specific? Can you also please provide a link for the TIMATIC search? A quick google search with "TIMATIC" didn't return meaningful results. TIMATIC (whatever it is) seems to be more relevant to coming into Romania by plain than by train, since I get a lot of iata website with it.

Comment: @woza I edited to clarify; since you've been to none of those countries, you're good (but *may* have to fill in a declaration form)

Comment: Thx! +1. I will leave accept the answer later though, to not discourage other readers if they have new information, since the situation changes rapidly.